# Can not find field_image(image) in drupal 7.24

Tags: media

I am new to Drupal. I am using a beginners guide pdf to get accustomed to it. It says at point 10 that :

- Now, we will move on to the image property. We are going to use an existing field
  for this property. In the Add existing field section, enter image for the Label. Select
  Image: field_image (Image) from the Field to share drop-down, and click on the
  Save button.

But in my installation:

[image: screendump]

I find no `field_image (image)`! What has happend?

Answer (score 0):

An image field will only appear as an "existing field" if it has already been defined for some content type.  The tutorial you're following assumes it does exist.  It look like this is not the case in your configuration. By default, the standard *Article* content type has an image field.  You may have removed it, or deleted the *Article* type.

If there is no existing type with an image field, you need to add it as a new field, as shown below:

[image]

If no *Image* field appears in this menu, you may need to enable the core **Image** module. To do so, navigate to: *Home » Administration » Modules*. Then locate the **Image** module in the core sectio, make sure there is a tickmark next to it, and click *Save configuration*.

Comment: thanks! thanks for the help. It is actually what u have said. thanks again! my miss-assumption.